# Push Next Div (Shipped from) downwards if previous Div (for account and risk of messrs) content is more,

Tags: html, css

When my DIV (For Account and risk of messrs) content increases, the DIV (shipped from) should move down, and if it decreases, the DIV (shipped from) should move up. I tried making additional DIVs, tried both the positions relative and absolute but with no success, I will appreciate if someone could help me in the right direction, as I am just learning html and css.

Here is my code.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>

    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }

    .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: khaki;
    margin: auto;

    }

    div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    }


    #div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    }


    #div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;

    }


    #div3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    }


    #div4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    }


    #div5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    }


    #div6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 400px;

    }


    #div7 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;

    }


    #div8 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 300px;

    }


    #div9 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 500px;

    }



    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <div id="div1">Container No. FFAU2203078</div>
    <div id="div2">Serial No. 783</div>
    <div id="div3">Invoice No. DTM/16200158</div>
    <div id="div4">Dated: 19-04-2023</div>
    <div id="div5">For Account & Risk of Messrs:</div>
    <div id="div7">
    <p>UAB IMLITEX<br>
    EUROPOS AVE. 124, KAUNAS<br>
    LT-46351, LITHUANIA<br></p> 
    </div>


    <div id="div9">Shipped from: PORT QASIM PAKISTAN TO CONSTANTA ROMANIA</div>

    <div id="div6">Negotiated with:</div>
    <div id="div8">UAB IMLITEX
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this? ordinary invoice print page use table tag.
and it makes that auto height you want.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: khaki;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .container h1{
      text-align:center;
      font-size:26px;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      padding:20px;
      text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .container table{
      width:100%;
      table-layout:fixed;
      font-size:14px;      
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      line-height:1.6;
    }
    
    .container table th{
      text-align:left;
      border:solid 1px blue;
      padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    .container table th span{
        display:inline-block;
        min-width:120px;
    }    
    .container table td{
      border:solid 1px green;
      padding-bottom:20px;
      vertical-align:top;
    }
    .container table td p{
      font-weight:bold;      
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1>INVOICE</h1>
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col width="40%">
          <col width="10%">
          <col width="40%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                <div><span>Container No.</span> FFAU2203078</div>
                <div><span>Serial No.</span> 783</div>
                <div><span>Invoice No.</span> DTM/16200158</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <p>For Account & Risk of Messrs:</p> 
                <div>
                   UAB IMLITEX<br>
                   EUROPOS AVE. 124, KAUNAS<br>
                   LT-46351, LITHUANIA
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <p>Negotiated with:</p>
                <div>
                  UAB IMLITEX
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <p>Shipped from:</p>
                  <div>
                    PORT QASIM PAKISTAN TO CONSTANTA ROMANIA
                  </div>
              </td>                 
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>         
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, I will definitely try your solution, take care.